# Using the UE4 headers/classes in a separate C++ project without the editor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I'm working on a C++ .dll plugin that gets passed UE4 classes like FName, UClass, FPlatformTime, etc for a game that I do not have the source code of. I would like to access the passed objects and view/modify their class members in my plugin.

Adding `UnrealEngine\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public` as additional include directory and then including `#include "UObject/NameTypes.h"` in my source file results in a seemingly endless amount of missing defines in headers like Build.h, Platform.h.

What is the correct way to include the UE4 classes in a simple Visual Studio C++ project without using the editor?

I've compiled a small UE4 project and I'm currently using the UE4 class headers extracted from its .pdb as the output is simple enough but I'd like to use the proper UE4 headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the UE4 solution, take a look at various programs, such as "BlankProgram" and "SlateViewer". These use UE4 modules and are built using UnrealBuildTool, but you could create your own program and only link to the UE4 modules that you need. This will effectively let you create a lightweight program without unneeded stuff such as UMG or media players, for example.

One downside to this is that, due to how UnrealBuildTool works, your program must reside inside the engine's "Source/Programs" folder and follow a simple, but non-negotiable template (i.e. it needs to have a <YourProgram.Target.cs> file where its type is set to "Program").

Best of luck!

Comment: Is it still true that Programs must be placed into the Engines Source/Programs folder in 4.2.7?

Answer (score -1):

Unreal Engine types are meant to be used with Unreal Engine, they are not designed to be used in a pure C++ project outside of the Unreal Engine ecosystem.